# Procedurally offsetting animation while keeping the curve of the animation

Tags: animation, modifiers

I am working on a walk cycle, and the movement of the legs is based on an empty following a path. The value I am animating is the offset of the follow path modifier.

I would like to animate one leg and use the same movement on the other by connecting the second leg's offset value via a driver. The problem is if I just copy the offset value as a driver, and simply add to it say 50, that does offset the animation, but the curve of it will stay the same, making the timing of the animation asymmetrical.

I've seen the technique in this video, but he does not explain this part:
https://youtu.be/AWnfeH2aeR4?list=PLRTjJoFOwyIxhpfI-vT3wGZUZLoiZG6Zq&t=375

It does work by simply copying the keyframes then offsetting those, but it would be nice to keep it procedural for easier changes later.

Here's a very simple demonstration of the problem. So what I would like to achieve is that it is offset in time, but it still has the fast part of the animation at the top of the circle, and the slow at the bottom. Obviously my method is wrong, but I could not think of an alternative.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_USZNpcttivmV0kwMR0V93UsIP-p9cTx/view?usp=sharing

Another note - this is exactly the behavior I'd like to replicate, sadly this plugin is way outdated and looks to be discontinued.

https://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/537-arewo-gui-a-detailed-description.html

Comment: i would recommend providing blend file because you didn't show us any settings you made, so that we can advice you precisely.

Comment: @Chris It is a model that I've purchased that I'm trying to animate so I should not just upload it i think, but I'll try and make some demonstration of the problem.

Comment: @SzilárdEgyed Yes, thanks. A reduced, toy version of the problem would help you out, too, I guess.. it wouldn't be a waste of your time, and it would help us a lot.

Comment: @RobinBetts I've attached an example file to my question! Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you scale the second path with x:-1 -> is this what you wanna achieve?